# How to overwrite the memory segment of a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to pass the passphrase to luks through a bash variable to unlock multiple device with the same passphrase without typing it multiple times. Once I've done that I would like  to overwrite the memory segment of that variable so the passphrase isn't in the ram anymore. Is there a way to do that ?

Edit : Since it seems impossible I have a subsequent question : the passphrase will be stored in some random place. How would an attacked be able to find and recover that passphrase from the ram ?

Comment: Even if you're successful in doing so, all the processes that you've fed with that password to perform the unlock already had 'contaminated` the memory multiple times with it. So this will likely become a never ending battle. Not even accounting for the kernel itself that handled the keyboard input and only god knows where it can be even stored in or not.

Comment: @threadp I'm just feeding cryptsetup

Comment: There's no documentation around how the shell does memory management of transient strings. Thus, even if a mechanism for overwriting content in-place did exist, it would be depending on implementation-defined behavior and able to break at any time. So the only safe answer is "no, you can't do that".

Comment: ...now, what you *should* do is make sure that swap is either encrypted or disabled before entering this code (of course), and then ensure that your OS is configured to zero out pages of unallocated memory -- that way you at least have some moderate level of confidence that your shell's memory state is inaccessible after it's exited. But how to do that is an OS-dependent system administration question (that could go into which specific patches &c. are applied to your kernel), not something StackOverflow is a great forum for.